# Force normal font

Tags: fonts

I don't know if this is a stupid question but is it possible to force every font to be a normal or an `\mdseries` font? I've searched for an hour for solutions but only found how to force a normal font within, say, an italic font; but this is not what I wanted.

Below is my MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
{\mdseries \textbf{summa} \textit{cum} \textsc{laude}}
\end{document}
```

So how do you make the outcome to be 'summa cum laude' instead of '**summa** *cum* ʟᴀᴜᴅᴇ'?

Comment: `\renewcommand{\itshape}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\bfseries}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\scshape}{\normalfont}`

Comment: Simplest approach seems to be to not use font comands instead of applying them and then breaking them.

Comment: @Johannes_B: Yes, but can be tedious.

Comment: May I ask what's the use case for this? Why do you want the font attribute commands to be ignored?

Comment: @siracusa: I think there's a bunch of  existing `.tex` documents and it is too much work to replace everything perhaps over and over again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some version with a `switch` from one 'style' to another 'style'

I've used the version without `\text...` commands just for comparison.

```
\documentclass{article}

\let\textscorig\textsc
\let\textbforig\textbf
\let\textitorig\textit


\newcommand{\MakeAllLookTheSameAndBoring}{%
  \renewcommand{\textsc}[1]{##1}%
  \renewcommand{\textbf}[1]{##1}%
  \renewcommand{\textit}[1]{##1}%
}

\newcommand{\MakeAllLookDifferent}{%
  \let\textsc\textscorig
  \let\textbf\textbforig
  \let\textit\textitorig
}


\begin{document}

\MakeAllLookTheSameAndBoring

{\mdseries summa cum laude}

{\mdseries \textbf{summa} \textit{cum} \textsc{laude}}

\MakeAllLookDifferent

{\mdseries summa cum laude}

{\mdseries \textbf{summa} \textit{cum} \textsc{laude}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is no really simple solution, so here an MWE with an extended version of Christian Hupfer's comment. Your normal font is then defined by `\rmfamily`, `\mdseries` and `\upshape`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\let\sffamily\rmfamily
\let\ttfamily\rmfamily
\let\bfseries\mdseries
\let\scshape\upshape
\let\slshape\upshape
\let\itshape\upshape
\let\em\upshape

\begin{document}
{\mdseries \textbf{summa} \textit{cum} \textsc{laude}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Redefine `\selectfont` to always issue `\fontseries{m}` and `\fontshape{n}`:

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretocmd\selectfont{\fontshape{n}\fontseries{m}}{}{}
```

If you want a version where the font is only locally uniformized,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\LetLtxMacro\standardselectfont\selectfont
\LetLtxMacro\boringselectfont\selectfont
\xpretocmd\boringselectfont{\fontshape{n}\fontseries{m}}{}{}
\def\BORINGFONTS{\LetLtxMacro\selectfont\boringselectfont}
\def\VARIEDFONTS{\LetLtxMacro\selectfont\standardselectfont}

\begin{document}

{\mdseries \textbf{summa} \textit{cum} \textsc{laude}}

\BORINGFONTS

{\mdseries \textbf{summa} \textit{cum} \textsc{laude}}

\VARIEDFONTS

{\mdseries \textbf{summa} \textit{cum} \textsc{laude}}

{\BORINGFONTS{\mdseries \textbf{summa} \textit{cum} \textsc{laude}}}

{\mdseries \textbf{summa} \textit{cum} \textsc{laude}}

\end{document}
```

[image]